# Do floor and ceiling function have the same inequality?

Tags: inequality

$\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \le \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor \le \frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$

$\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \le \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil \le \frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Is $n$ an integer?

Comment: Yes. You can prove it by brute force. Although notice that for each case the closed interval is of length 1 containing n/2 at middle, so floor and ceiling will behave alike.

Comment: If $n=6.1$, then the ceiling gives $4$, which exceeds $(n/2)+(1/2)$. See comment by @Sambo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that both equations are true iff (if and only if) $n$ is an integer. The case where $n$ is an integer is pretty simple. If $n$ isn't an integer then $\lfloor n\rfloor+1=\lceil n\rceil$ and thus, as $k\le\lfloor n\rfloor,\,\lceil n\rceil\le k+1$ for $k=\frac{n-1}{2}$ we know that equality holds everywhere, which means that $k$ and therefore $n$ are integers.